# Optimizing recursive backtrack

Tags: java, recursion, optimization, backtracking

I solved a variation of the knapsack problem by backtracking all of the possible solutions. Basically 0 means that item is not in the backpack, 1 means that the item is in the backpack. Cost is the value of all items in the backpack, we are trying to achieve the lowest value possible while having items of every "class". Each time that a combination of all classes is found, I calculate the value of all items and if it's lower than globalBestValue, I save the value. I do this is `verify()`.

Now I'm trying to optimize my recursive backtrack. My idea was to iterate over my array as it's being generated and return the generator if the "cost" of my generated numbers is already higher then my current best-value, therefore the combination currently being generated can't be the new best-value and can be skipped.

However with my optimization, my backtrack is not generating all the values and it actually skips the "best" value I'm trying to find. Could you tell me where the problem is?

```
private int globalBestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int[] arr;

public KnapSack(int numberOfItems) {
    arr = new int[numberOfItems];
}

private void generate(int fromIndex) {
    int currentCost = 0; // my optimisation starts here
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (currentCost > globalBestValue) {
            return;
        }
        if (arr[i] == 1) {
            currentCost += allCosts.get(i);
        }
    } // ends here
    if (fromIndex == arr.length) {
        verify();
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        arr[fromIndex] = i;
        generate(fromIndex + 1);
    }
}

public void verify() {
            // skipped the code verifying the arr if it's correct, it's long and not relevant
            if (isCorrect == true && currentValue < globalBestValue) {
                globalBestValue = currentValue;
            }else{
                return;
            }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of code missing like the definitions of `arr`, `allCosts`, `verifiy()` etc. - so you might need to post a [mcve]. However you actually seem to be looking for an optimization algorithm so you might search for that. Just note that there are exact algorithms that might be costlier in terms of memory and time as well as heuristic algorithms that don't cost that much but might not be able to find the best solution - just a "good enough" one.

Comment: I further assume `currectCost > globalBestValue` is a typo and you mean `currentCost > globalBestValue`. Also we'd need to know how `globalBestValue` is set, i.e. if it is 0 or could contain only partial costs then this might be your problem.

Comment: @Thomas Hi, I fixed the typo and added a lot of code that should help you further understand my code. Skipped some parts of verify(), as it's over 30 lines and not relevant to the problem, but otherwise it's complete.

Comment: There are still some relevant parts missing, e.g. what is `allCosts`? How is `currentValue` calculated? However, I suspect the problem is `if(currentCost > globalBestValue)` - do you really want to compare the _costs_ with the _value_? I'm quite sure about what variation of the problem you're trying to solve but I'd assume that the value is meant to get higher while the cost is meant to get lower. The best solution might actually have higher costs than the current best's value so it would be skipped. Wouldn't you want to compare value vs. value and cost vs. cost?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, that's just my translation. I didn't share all the code, because the problem lies in generation, not in values. The problem is, that with my optimisation, the backtracking actually skips the best value, which is [1,0,0,1].

Comment: To compute the current costs you sum over the entire array, however only up to `fromIndex` is logically filled (the part after that is junk values that would be overwritten by this or later `generate` calls)

Comment: @harold Thanks! So I should do the verification only when the index is filled, in here: if (fromIndex == arr.length)? That won't save much resources, tho.

Comment: @Jack yea that wouldn't prune, but that's a nuclear solution anyway. Just be sure not to loop too far. `i < fromIndex` in the loop would be OK I think? E: well it still misses the potential cost of the unassigned units. And this whole cost/value thing still confuses me. If we're talking about minimizing cost, the empty solution is best, right?

Comment: @harold running my loop to fromIndex did the trick. The number of recursive calls is now halved and it's working correctly. Thank you so much!!! Edit: Hmm, just noticed your edit. Not sure, it works fine for a couple of my inputs. And we want the solution that's "correct", meaning that checks all the boxes in verify() and we want the solution with the lower possible cost. [0,0,0,0] doesn't check all the criteria. I skipped the code in verify() as I didn't consider it relevant, but I can share it if you want.

Comment: No I guess it's fine, it's just I'm getting confused about the costs here vs values in the previous question

Comment: @harold Thanks again, it's working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Pardon my bluntness, but your efforts at optimizing an inefficient algorithm can only be described as polishing the turd. You will not solve a knapsack problem of any decent size by brute force, and early return isn't enough. I have mentioned one approach to writing an efficient program on CodeReview SE; it requires a considerable effort, but you gotta do what you gotta do.
2. Having said that, I'd recommend you write the `arr` to console in order to troubleshoot the sequence. It looks like when you go back to the index `i-1`, the element at `i` remains set to 1, and you estimate the upper bound instead of the lower one. The following change might work: replace your code

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
       arr[fromIndex] = i;
       generate(fromIndex + 1);
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   arr[fromIndex] = 1;
   generate(fromIndex + 1);
   arr[fromIndex] = 0;
   generate(fromIndex + 1);
   ```

This turns it into a sort of greedy algorithm: instead of starting with `0000000`, you effectively start with `1111111`. And obviously, when you store the `globalBestValue`, you should store the actual data which gives it. But the main advice is: when your algorithm behaves weirdly, tracing is your friend.

Comment: Thanks. I know that bruteforcing isn't the most optimal way, but what I'm looking for with this project is just optimising backtrack, not turning backtrack into dynamic programming. I fixed my optimisation by running the first loop from 0 to fromIndex. This optimisation halved the number of all my recursive calls. Will look into your code too. Thanks again